# Angular 6 App and Server project structure

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

What is the proper project structure when creating an Angular 6 application, and an API server that share type definitions?

Example:

On the client:

```typescript
this.httpService.get<Hero[]>(apiUrl + '/heroes')
```

On the server:

```typescript
app.get('/heroes', async (req, res) => {
  const heroes: Hero[] = await db.Heroes.findAll<Hero>()
  res.status(200).send(heroes)
}
```

I need to share the `Hero` definition between projects.

- Do I build my server in a sub-directory of the angular app?
- Do I build my server app first, then reference its source code somehow from the Angular app?
- Do I build a third Models project, write all the definitions there, and somehow reference them?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a structure as follows,

[image]

where web is the front end and services is going to be your node/go services.

**`Do I build my server in a sub-directory of the angular app?`**

No , you can separate both.

**`Do I build my server app first, then reference its source code somehow from the Angular app?`**

Yes thats better so you do not have to worry about Model when you start with your angular app.

**`Do I build a third Models project, write all the definitions there, and somehow reference them?`**

Not necessary. You can have your models in your node project itself.

**`I need to share the Hero definition between projects.`**
I would strongly suggest not to do that, becauase sometimes you are not binding all properties on the front end. Have a separate Interface for your front end models.

Comment: Different models will be the exception.. How do I make a shared library for the majority?

Comment: You can use a share folder to use the shared ones